# How to abstract next/image from next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm only using the next/image from Next.js. Is there a way to only install next/image module and not the entire Next.js module. I tried doing the following -

```
"next/image": "^10.0.5",
"next/link": "^10.0.5",
```

But after doing npm install I'm getting the following error -

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "next/image": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sugamxp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-17T06_08_55_518Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such package `next/image`, it is just a folder inside `next` package, so no, you cannot install it separately.

Moreover, you can't use it separately without NextJs because it relies on NextJs server to optimize images on demand. I guess, you would need to find another solution if you want image optimization.